# How add a span after innerhtml text inside a div using jQuery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a document structure looks like this:

```
<div class="text">
     Send email 
</div>
```

How can I insert a **span** tag after the text so that the final document structure looks like:

```
<div class="text">
     Send email <span class="envelope"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [**jQuery#append**](http://api.jquery.com/append/). I also print the `html` structure of the `div` to see what it is like.

```js
const div = $('.text');

div.append('<span class="envelope">Envelop</span>');

console.log(div.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text"> Send email </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method of jquery library it will add span after text.

```
$( "div.text" ).append( '<span class="envelope"></span>' );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Vanilla JS`, Try this.

```js
 document.querySelector('.text').innerHTML += `<span class="envelope">sss</span>`;
```

```html
<div class="text">
 TEXT
</div>
```

Comment: `innerHTML` is not purposed to populate existing elements. Use `appendChild` or `insertAdjacentHTML` instead.